# Scale value needed to shrink one circle to match another?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a couple of circles that share the same center point. Both are already scaled down from a larger circle.

I know each circle's radius rather easily. I only have the larger circles "scale" value. Given each circle can have a random scale value that makes the circle larger and smaller (and gives it a new radius), I'm trying to figure out how much more I need to scale that outer circle down to match the smaller circle's radius.

On a programming level, I've tried scaling down the larger circle at very large iterations until match -- but that is really tedious. And I'd like to understand the math behind this all.

Does anyone know how I might go about solving this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I may have misinterpreted the question, but you could just get the radius of your "standard" circle with scale = 1 and then use the radius of B to figure out it's scale

$$r_1 = \frac{r_A}{s_A} = \frac{1.936}{0.498} = 3.887$$

$$s_B = \frac{r_B}{r_1} = \frac{0.637}{3.887} = 0.164$$